# Order in which excel dependent formulas are calculated

Tags: vba, excel, dependencies

I want to understand how the interdependent excel formulas are calculated specially I am interested in the order and process

Simple example 
e.g. I have two formulas in excel spreadsheet,

> ```
> cell A4 contains =SUM(A1:A3) 
> cell A5 contains =Round(A4)
> ```

I am assuming A5 Waits until A4 is calculated and that's **somehow** tracked and implemented by excel internally.

1. Is my assumption right?
2. I wanted to get a better understanding of this "**somehow**"

May be excel uses some dependency graph , is threading involved? etc. anything that helps me understand!

The motive behind the question is, I have an Excel-Addin from some third-party software and the formulas I used in the sheet makes me suspect that each cell is waiting for other to execute first hence going into a lock state.

Comment: Some great info here: http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel builds a dependency tree and walks through it calculating each cell in the order you would expect.  However, since there can be circular references it may do multiple passes until nothing changes (or the change is very small).  The max passes is controlled by the "Iteration" setting.

In Excel 2007 and greater, there is support for multi-threaded calculation.

For your simple case where there are no circular references, most likely the third-party addin is doing something funky if Excel is freezing.  Here is an MSDN article describing the calculation process in detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891(v=office.15).aspx